# Unable to deploy smart contract to rinkeby using ledger wallet?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, react

I am trying to deploy smart contract using ledger wallet. But i keep getting the error **cant subscribe to new header**. However i get the transaction hash but cant receive the contract instance and receipt.

[image]

```
var myContract = new my_web3.eth.Contract(this.state.abi);
        myContract.deploy({
            from: this.state.defaultAddr,
            data:this.state.byteCode

        })
        .send({
            from: this.state.defaultAddr,
            gas: 1500000,
            gasPrice: '30000000'
        })
        .on('error',error=>{

            console.log(error)
            this.setState({
             errors:error
            ,infoHidden:true
            ,errorHidden:false
            })
        })
        .on('transactionHash', transactionHash=>{ 
         console.log(transactionHash) })
        .on('receipt',receipt=>{
           console.log(receipt) // contains the new contract address
        })
        .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ 
          console.log(confirmationNumber) })
        .then(newContractInstance=>{
            console.log(newContractInstance) // instance with the new 
                 contract address







                this.setState({
                Contract:newContractInstance,
                infoHidden:false,
                errorHidden:true})
            console.log("Contract 
            Address"+newContractInstance.options.address);
            this.props.history.push({
                pathname:'/save',
                state:{
                // ABI:response.data.data.abi,
                // byteCode:response.data.data.byteCode,
                ContractAddress:newContractInstance.options.address,
                ABI:this.state.abi,
                    }  
                    })


        })
```

Connection Snippet

```
   var my_web3
    let account;
    const rpcUrl = "https://rinkeby.infura.io/";

   const use_ledger =localStorage.walletAccessMechanismType;
   console.log(use_ledger)
    if(use_ledger =="ledger")
    {
    const engine = new ProviderEngine();
    const getTransport = () => TransportU2F.create();
    const ledger = createLedgerSubprovider(getTransport, {
    networkId: 4, // 3 == Ropsten testnet
    });
    engine.addProvider(ledger);
    engine.addProvider(new RpcSubprovider({ rpcUrl }));
   engine.start();
   my_web3 = new Web3(engine); 
  } else if(typeof(web3) === 'undefined') {
    my_web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcUrl));
  } else {
     my_web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);    
    }
```

Comment: How do you setup your web3 instance? It seems you are using web3 v1.0, in that version to subscribe to events you have to use the websocket version of infura, because RPC version does not support polling events.

Comment: I have added the connection snipped above @Ismael

Comment: If you could refer me some useful material that'd be great.. i'm new to ledger.
however i tried the same approach with a demo app and it worked perfectly but now it's giving errors with the new one.

Comment: It is explained in the answers to this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25451/infura-web3-provider-for-events-get-watch, one of them provides an example how to use with websockets.

Comment: Tried it but i still cant deploy my contract using nano ledger .. how ever every thing works well when im using metamask

Comment: @Ismael can you take a look at my connection of ledger above and suggest a fix

Comment: Sorry but I did not work with a ledger authorization yet. It is better if you create a new question for the ledger issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. My issue was solved it seemed that infura only allows RPC while through ledgerhq library i wasnt able to do that or due to web3. So all i had to do was instead of injecting my ledgerhq provider,i used infura default provider and i was able to solve the issue.
any way thank you very much for your support