# Accessing the network through light node

Tags: events, web3.py, light-clients, filters

I've been trying, unsuccessfully, to make a web3.py app that needs to catch events, with the use of filters. After hours and hours of testing it appeared the problem was that Infura, which is the provider I used, doesnt support filters. Therefore I need to set up a node but do not really have the space available to maintain a full node. Can a light node handle filters properly? I do not need old data, i just need to catch events from now on. Thanks

Comment: Infura has support for events, you need to use websockets and web3 v1.0 see this answer for an example https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/45418