# Trying and failing to switch my dapp from local node to infura, please help?

Tags: events, nodejs, infura

I have a nodejs 'server' running that listens for events on the blockchain. Currently I have this line in my code:

```
var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");
```

But I'm fed up paying $40 every month for my node. I want to switch to infura. I signed up, added my project, got project ID. Then changed this line of code to:

```
var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/PROJECTID");
```

And I get a whole load of errors as per https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKkNw.png. What's going on? What am I doing wrong?

> Error: The method eth_newFilter does not exist/is not
>   available

Comment: "And I get a whole load of errors." Maybe tell us what those errors are. :-)

Comment: good point :) updated my Q with the errors. I think it's the same set of errors when I use localhost when parity isn't running. It just can't connect to a node.

Comment: are you listening for events using websockets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infura web3 provider for Events (.get & .watch)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25451/infura-web3-provider-for-events-get-watch)

Comment: @pumpkinfeet Infura only support events through websockets.

Comment: Please share the actual errors, in text, not a screenshot. Screenshots are not searchable or accessible.

Comment: What is your server doing exactly, is it read only? Or are you writing to the Blockchain?

Comment: I am listening to events, so it sounds like I need websockets. But I also understand that I need web3 1.0 for websockets. So I'll need to upgrade everything to that and then try this again :)